# Trigger to add lookup field not updating to null if no match is found during update

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the trigger below that should update two lookup fields. One looks up to a rate schedule record based on the name. This works fine to compare and update that lookup. The other lookup is for a monthly commission record that should find the record where the owner of the deal commission record matches the sales rep for the monthly commission record. It should also match on the month the deal was closed in.

This works as expected until I add in the last else statement to account for times where the owner changes and does not have a monthly commission record. In that case I want to clear the lookup field. essentially the only time the field will update correctly when the else statement is added is if the owner is assigned to the last sales rep in the list 'monthly commissions' Is there a different way to handle this?

TRIGGER;

```
trigger UpdateAnnualCommPlanLookup on Deal_Commission__c (before 
insert, before update) {

TSGADX__ADX_Settings__c sett = TSGADX__ADX_Settings__c.getInstance();

IF(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
{
    IF(sett.Enable_Commission_Triggers__c)
    {
        for(Deal_Commission__c dc : Trigger.new)
        {
            IF(dc.Annual_Rate_Override__c == FALSE)
            {
                UpdateAnnualCommPlanHelper.updateCompPlan(trigger.new, 
Trigger.old);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

CLASS:

```
public with sharing class UpdateAnnualCommPlanHelper {

public static void updateCompPlan(List<Deal_Commission__c> newDealCommission, 
List<Deal_Commission__c> oldDealCommission) 
{
    List<Annual_Commission_Rates__c> annualCommList = [SELECT Id, Name from 
Annual_Commission_Rates__c where Inactive__c = FALSE];
    List<Monthly_Commission_And_Bonus__c> monthlyCommission = [SELECT Id, Sales_Rep__c, 
Commission_Month__c FROM Monthly_Commission_And_Bonus__c];

    IF(annualCommList != NULL)
    {
        FOR(Annual_Commission_Rates__c acr : annualCommList)
        {
                FOR(Deal_Commission__c dc : newDealCommission)
                {
                    String acrName = acr.Name;
                    String dcYear = dc.Commission_Year__c;
                    IF (acrName.Equals(dcYear)) 
                    {
                        dc.Annual_Commission_Rates__c = acr.Id;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    FOR(Monthly_Commission_And_Bonus__c mcb : monthlyCommission)
    {
        FOR(Deal_Commission__c dc : newDealCommission)
            {
                String mcSalesRep = mcb.Sales_Rep__c;
                String dcOwner = dc.OwnerId;
                String mcbMonth = mcb.Commission_Month__c;
                String ComMonth = dc.Commission_Month__c;
                IF(mcSalesRep.equals(dcOwner) && mcbMonth.equals(ComMonth))
                {
                    dc.Monthly_Commission_Bonus__c = mcb.Id;
                }else {
                    dc.Monthly_Commission_Bonus__c = NULL;
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is not sustainable. It will eventually crash in production. You must limit your queries to only the records you need, and utilize Map objects to organize your data.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, I changed the trigger to use sets to limit, maps to organize, and changed how I was iterating over them. The fields are updating as they should now.